# android: alarm task closed on application killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

On my application I want to execute a task every few minutes, and for this I added an alarm manager to run on elapsed time. The code is simple:

```
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000 /* Initial run in 1 second */,
            OnBootReceiver.REPEAT_PERIOD, /* 10 minutes */
            pi);
```

of course I have the broadcast receiver:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     //implementation here
}
```

I run this code on main activity of my application and in a Broadcast (OnBootReceiver) to ensure that my code runs on app start and in each boot.

My issue is when the operating system closes the bg applications. If I go to tasks manager and I run Clear Memory command, my application is closed and I don't get any alarm notification.

**How do I keep receiving the alarm notifications on my code in this scenario?**

Answer (score 2):

> If I go to tasks manager and I run Clear Memory command, my application is closed and I don't get any alarm notification.

Since a "Clear Memory command" does not exist in standard Android, the precise implementation of this feature will only be known by your device manufacturer.

> How do I keep receiving the alarm notifications on my code in this scenario?

Probably you don't. Most likely, the device manufacturer is doing some of the stuff that Force Stop does in Settings, including unscheduling your alarms. You can confirm this theory by running `adb shell dumpsys alarm` before and after you "run Clear Memory command" to see what changed with your alarm.

Note that even on devices that lack a "Clear Memory command", the user can Force Stop you from Settings, and your alarms are removed.

Comment: The user has a way to stop using the application (a close button), what do I need is to ensure that only the user can close the app and not the OS.

Comment: @ZelterAdy: You can build your own mobile operating system. Or, you can download the Android source code, remove the Force Stop button from Settings, rebuild that source code, convert it into a ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on whatever devices that you can. Otherwise, the user has final control over their device, and that includes Force Stop and any equivalents offered by device manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For your activity, in the manifest xml, put:

```
android:persistent="true"
```

EDIT:

Please see this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/nU0e3aoBlSY and  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29

Comment: Thanks - those links help if I have a service, but I don't. I try to avoid using a service, I implemented my app with an alarm receiver and before to change this into a service I want to try to find a way to fix it on the actual form.